# How does "[]" work in this code snippet ? Is this a ES6 feature?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I wanted to make an array of objects from an existing array

i.e [1,2,3] should become => [{1:1} , {2:1} , {3:1}]

The code below was my initial attempt but the result was [{element : 1} , {element : 1}, {element : 1}]

```
let scores = [1,2,3];
let sr = [];
scores.forEach(element => {
    sr.push({ element : 1 });
});
```

I put square brackets around "element" and to my surprise it worked.

```
let scores = [1,2,3];
let sr = [];
scores.forEach(element => {
    sr.push({ [element] : 1 }); // this works but I have no clue how :(
});
```

I am sorry to have worded this question vaguely but I wanted to know the reason behind it badly.

Comment: Yes, ES6. It evaluates the code inside the brackets as an expression instead of a static member label. The result of the expression becomes the member name, much like how `myObj[ element ]` evaluates the expression inside the brackets.

Comment: ...also, this is a textbook case for `.map()`... `let sr = scores.map(el => ({[el] : 1}))`

Comment: Its called [`Computed property names`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) and its a ES6 feature

Comment: ...are you sure you want an array of objects, each of which have a single, unique key? Using either a single object or an array of objects with `{id: element, value: 1}`  is more common, but then I don't know your use here.

Answer (score 3):

This is done when you want to set a dynamic `key`. I suggest to use `.map`:

```js
const scores = [1,2,3];
const sr = scores.map( element => ({ [element] : 1 }) );
console.log(sr);
```

Comment: the feature is called _computed properties_

Answer (score 2):

so [] in that context resolves as an expression (which was always weird to me that it wasn't () inside object property names to resolve as an expression...), but yeah, it's assigning the value of the var to the key instead of directly defining the key as 'element' (the default).
it's ES6 syntax, and I don't think it has a name exactly...

```
let sr = scores.map(element => ({ [element] : 1 }));
```

is also faster for what you want to do.

Comment: The `[]` corresponds to the previously existing behavior that allowed expression evaluation as the property name.

Comment: thank you, forgot it was before es6... things jumble.